# passing function as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have recently started a project and now I am trying to pass an onClick function as a prop of a Menubar so when I click on the image in Taskbar it displays the Menubar content

```
import React from 'react'
import "./MenuBar.css" 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

 function MenuBar() {
    
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const [close, setClose]= React.useState(false)

const TaskBar=()=>{
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

   
  
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  



return (   
 
     <div className="taskbar">

            <img onPress={() => handleOpen(true)}  className="menu" 
            <MenuBar onPress={() => handleClose(false)}/>
```

Comment: Maybe `<img onClick={handleOpen} className="menu"`

Comment: It´s easy just set ther property `onClick={() => this.handleOpen()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pass the function, `handleOpen`, not the result of executing the function, `handleOpen()`. Does this work?

`<img onClick={handleOpen} className="menu" />`

**Update**

Based on your edited code, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./MenuBar.css" 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function MenuBar(props) {
  return <div className='my-menu-bar-content'>
    <span>MENU</span>
    <p>This is some sample menu content.</p>
    <button onClick={props.closeMenu}>Close</button>
  </div>
}

function TaskBar(props){
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  function openMenu(){
    setIsMenuOpen(true)
  }
  function closeMenu(){
    setIsMenuOpen(false)
  }
  return (   
    <div className="taskbar">
      <img onClick={openMenu} className="menu" />
      {isMenuOpen ? <MenuBar closeMenu={closeMenu} />: null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It says "setOpen is not defined"

Comment: It looks like your code has multiple components being defined, can you check the formatting a bit? It looks like setOpen is defined in your `MenuBar` component, but not in your `TaskBar` component, which is where you are passing it into the image.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleOpen' of undefined

Comment: Can you clean up the formatting of the code you posted? It doesn't look like MenuBar is properly terminated so I can't tell what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a typo in my answer. Since this is a functional component, we won't use `this.handleOpen`, just 'handleOpen`. It was saying undefined since it doesn't know what this is. Does it work now?

Comment: Also note that you need to pass `setOpen` into your `TaskBar` component since it is defined in MenuBar, in which case it will probably look like `props.setOpen`.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: This redirects me to the page but when I click on image same error appears ``` function TaskBar (){ const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false); const handleOpen = () => setOpen(false); return ( <div className="taskbar"> <img onClick={() => this.handleOpen()} className="menu" ```

Comment: @tekila Can you post the code as an edit to your original message? It won't format properly here. Also you are still using `this.handleOpen` instead of `handleOpen`--in a functional component you shouldn't use `this`; the `handleOpen` method is already in scope.

Comment: I have fixed that error but nothing happens now when I click on the image

Comment: @tekila as written right now, your MenuBar function isn't terminated and therefore includes your TaskBar item. Is this intended? Is this copied and pasted from your code exactly or is it abbreviated? If TaskBar lives inside of MenuBar then I don't know how you are calling and MenuBar, and setOpen would be declared twice.

Comment: @tekila I wrote some updated code in the answer; did I guess correctly about what you are trying to accomplish? If not please let me know.

Comment: I need to put on onClick={CloseMenu}on the image

Answer (score 0):

In your case `<img onClick={this.handleOpen()} className="menu"` will looped

You should pass the only function without invoke it like this -> `<img onClick={this.handleOpen} className="menu"`

Answer (score 0):

- handleOpen function needs some modification, I think.
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(!open);
- And rest of the part should be something like this.
  <img onClick={this.handleOpen} ...